# Hide "Edit Item" Menu Item

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i have a serious trouble hiding ECB buttons in SharePoint 2010. I've read an article that says that I must create a copy of core.js file and comment the AddCheckInCheckOutMenuItems function. I've tried it and I have also referenced my custom core.js file. However it is still not working. It seems like Sharepoint is only calling the function from core.js or its somehow overwriting my function . Anyone here with the same problem or anyone that could solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer:
http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/29/hide-menu-ecb/

You can also try CSS to hide ECB button, if Javascript didn't work for you.